# preg_matchvalidation

Tags: php, validation

Okay, everything I've checked on this site referring to validation isn't what I'm looking for.

What I'm looking to do is a minimum length and maximum length of a value in firstname and secondname, this is the code which I currently have.

```
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $errors = array();

                 if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
            $fn = $_POST['firstname'];
        } else {
            $errors[] = "You have not entered a first name";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['secondname'])) {
            $sn = $_POST['secondname'];
        } else {
            $errors[] = "You have not entered a second name";
        }
```

I was just wondering how would I apply preg_match to those which the minimum is 4 letters and the maximum is 15?

I do know it's something to do with

```
if(preg_match('/^[A-Z \'.-]{4,15}$/i', $_POST['firstname']))
```

In doing this I tried to do

```
    if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && preg_match('/^[A-Z \'.-]{4,15}$/i', $_POST['firstname')) {
```

But that also gave me an error :/

Could anyone give me a solution for this?

Thanks!

UPDATE:-

Nvm, I found a way around it. I just did this

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
        if (preg_match('/^[A-Z \'.-]{4,15}$/i', $_POST['firstname'])) {
            $fn = $_POST['firstname'];
        } else {
            $errors[] = "<center> <h3> You must enter between 4 and 15 characters! </h3></center>";                  
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a name";
```

}
For both the firstname and secondname. :)

Comment: *"But that also gave me an error :/"* - What error? Please add the text of the error message to your question.

Comment: @hakre I'm doing my code as server side (not client side), since the code is server side, when there's an error, the page just goes blank. So I can't really provide the error code for it if it doesn't appear.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to show the error.

Comment: @FizzyBear: Okay, first point to improve: Enable error logging (so you can look into the error log what went wrong) and/or [display the errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors): `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @hakre At this stage, it's just going to a page where if the user leaves the field incomplete. So it's just not validating properly.

Tried both the code you both provided, it does nothing.

Comment: @Robbie I'm just waiting for this to finish then I can submit the actual answer then mark it as answered :)

Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 1 hour. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around it. I just did this

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
            if (preg_match('/^[A-Z \'.-]{4,15}$/i', $_POST['firstname'])) {
                $fn = $_POST['firstname'];
            } else {
                $errors[] = "<center> <h3>You must enter between 4 and 15 characters!</h3> </center>";                  
            }
        } else {
            $errors[] = "You have not entered a name";
   }
```

For both the firstname and secondname.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `strlen()` to get the string length, and then test it against your limits ?

```
$length = strlen($nick);
if ($length > 3 AND $length < 16) {
    //Do STuff
} else {
    //Do stuff for failed requirement
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use preg_match, not strlen(). :)

Comment: preg_match to control min max chars in a string is not the best approach! Try strlen() what is the problem with this?
<?php $min=5; $max=25; $len = strlen($str); if((($min != '') && ($len < $min)) || (($max != '') && ($len > $max))) echo "warning" else //DO STUFF!